# Angular 4 - open select on label click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I open the `select` when I click on the `label`?

```
<label>filter per category: <span>{{ articleListService.selectedCategory }}</span></label>
<select #category (change)="articleListService.categoryFilter2()" [(ngModel)]="articleListService.formModel.category">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option *ngFor="let category of articleListService.laCategoryList" value="{{ category.id }}">
        {{ category.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Thank you for you help, i'm lost

Answer (score 1):

Good question, this is more of an HTML 5 thing then an Angular thing. You are going to want to use a `for={id}` .

So in your specific code, it would look something like this.

```html
<label for="category">filter per category: [cat group shows here]</label>

<select id="category" #category (change)="articleListService.categoryFilter2()" [(ngModel)]="articleListService.formModel.category">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option *ngFor="let category of articleListService.laCategoryList" value="{{category.id }}">
    {{ category.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

- For further reference on how to use for with labels see official [MDN on labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Not in plain HTML and not in React. I don't know about Angular, but I assume it's the same case.

Comment: This doesn't open the option list just focus the select element

Answer (score 0):

Found an article that is similar to what you're asking but you have to have the label as a parent of the select?

https://medium.com/browserquirks/browserquirk-programmatically-opening-a-select-box-4ca745a8468f

or maybe try adding a template reference to the select, and then `@ViewChild('ThatReference') thatRef: ElementRef;`

then maybe when you click label, and it fires event to trigger click event on select via `this.thatRef.nativeElement.click()`?